# Do all of the special unitary groups SU(n) contain copies of the trivial group SU(1)?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I am new to group theory but trying to learn, and it seems that all of the higher special unitary groups SU(n) n>1 should contain copies of SU(1). Is this correct?

Comment: Be careful calling $SU(1)$ the "trivial group."

Comment: @Randall That's just what Wikipedia called it, as it has only one element https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group but I'm pretty new to this and still learning the terminology.

Comment: Ignore me.  I'm off a degree.  It is correctly "trivial."  And yes, all groups have a copy of the trivial group in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group is usually said to be a “copy” of another group if the two are isomorphic. In this sense, all groups, not just the groups $SU(n)$, contain a copy of the trivial group $SU(1)$, namely, the subgroup consisting only of the identity element.